# Alterar a cor de uma célula de acordo com o valor

Tags: php, html, css, table

Tenho uma página com uma tabela que mostra informações da quantidade de itens previstos pra serem realizados e a quantidade de itens que realmente foram realizados no final de cada mês.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Me foi pedido que, caso no mês tenha mais itens realizados que previstos, a célula que mostra a quantidade realizada ficasse verde e caso contrário, vermelha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Eu não tenho a menor ideia da possibilidade de fazer isso, mas se alguém souber como fazer, por favor, comenta aqui.

O código da tabela:

```
<!-- Main -->
        <div class="content-lg container">
            <div class="row margin-b-20">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h2>Prev x Real Month</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 sm-margin-b-50">

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        //Pegar o ID do botão clicado 
                        function abreModal (idR)
                        {
                            $.post("/Teste_Obeya/ajax.php", 
                            { id : idR }, function(content){
                                $(".modal-body").html(content); 
                            }, 'html');
                        }
                    </script>


                            <?php

                            require 'conn.php';

                            //Conexão e consulta ao Mysql
                            $qry = mysqli_query($lnk, "select * from qualite");

                            //Pegando os nomes dos campos
                            $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado

                            for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
                                $fields[] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($qry,$i)->name;
                            }

                            //Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
                            $table = '<table  class="table table-hover table-inverse"> <tr style="">';

                            for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
                                $table .= '<th style="padding-right:5px;">'.$fields[$i].'</th>';
                            }

                            //Montando o corpo da tabela
                            $table .= '<tbody >';
                            while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
                                $table .= '<tr>';
                                for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
                                    $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
                                }

                                // Adicionando botão de edição

                                $table .= '<td><form action="qualite-edicao.php" method="post">'; 
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="KPI" value="'.$r['KPI'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="PILOTE" value="'.$r['PILOTE'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN PREV" value="'.$r['JAN_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN REAL" value="'.$r['JAN_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV PREV" value="'.$r['FEV_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV REAL" value="'.$r['FEV_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR PREV" value="'.$r['MAR_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR REAL" value="'.$r['MAR_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR PREV" value="'.$r['ABR_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR REAL" value="'.$r['ABR_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI PREV" value="'.$r['MAI_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI REAL" value="'.$r['MAI_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN PREV" value="'.$r['JUN_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN REAL" value="'.$r['JUN_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL PREV" value="'.$r['JUL_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL REAL" value="'.$r['JUL_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO PREV" value="'.$r['AGO_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO REAL" value="'.$r['AGO_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET PREV" value="'.$r['SET_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET REAL" value="'.$r['SET_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT PREV" value="'.$r['OUT_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT REAL" value="'.$r['OUT_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV PREV" value="'.$r['NOV_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV REAL" value="'.$r['NOV_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ PREV" value="'.$r['DEZ_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ REAL" value="'.$r['DEZ_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></i> Editar </i></button>'; //
                                $table .= '</form></td>';



                                //MODAL COM O GRÁFICO
                                $table .= '<td><form action="graf-qualite.php" method="post">'; 
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="KPI" value="'.$r['KPI'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="PILOTE" value="'.$r['PILOTE'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN PREV" value="'.$r['JAN PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN REAL" value="'.$r['JAN REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV PREV" value="'.$r['FEV PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV REAL" value="'.$r['FEV REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR PREV" value="'.$r['MAR PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR REAL" value="'.$r['MAR REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR PREV" value="'.$r['ABR PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR REAL" value="'.$r['ABR REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI PREV" value="'.$r['MAI PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI REAL" value="'.$r['MAI REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN PREV" value="'.$r['JUN PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN REAL" value="'.$r['JUN REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL PREV" value="'.$r['JUL PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL REAL" value="'.$r['JUL REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO PREV" value="'.$r['AGO PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO REAL" value="'.$r['AGO REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET PREV" value="'.$r['SET PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET REAL" value="'.$r['SET REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT PREV" value="'.$r['OUT PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT REAL" value="'.$r['OUT REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV PREV" value="'.$r['NOV PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV REAL" value="'.$r['NOV REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ PREV" value="'.$r['DEZ PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ REAL" value="'.$r['DEZ REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<!-- Button -->
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" name="button" onclick="abreModal(' . $r['ID'] .');">
                                              Gráfico
                                            </button>

                                            <!-- Modal -->

                                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" onload="click("button");">
                                              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Gráfico</h5>
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">


                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>'; //
                                $table .= '</form></td>';

                            }

                            //Finalizando a tabela
                            $table .= '</tbody></table>';


                            //Imprimindo a tabela
                            echo '<div class="table-table" style="overflow-x:auto;">';
                            echo $table;
                    ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Esse é o banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mariana, você precisa especificar melhor como seu projeto trabalha, se é em php submetendo respostas em html para o navegador, ou se funciona com javascript e ajax fazendo requisições ao servidor e devolvendo respostas em json ou xml. Na sua pergunta não mostrou qualquer pedaço de código do seu projeto. Complicado lhe fornecer  caminhos para resolução do problema.

Comment: Opa, eu esqueci de colocar o código. Desculpa, esqueci mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou ter que inventar nomes para te ajudar porque não postou o código sql como os nomes das colunas que retornam os valores do banco de dados.

Pelo que vejo seu laço **While** response com os números de linhas correspondentes a sua consulta no banco de dados enquanto laço **FOR** lê campo a campo retornado da consulta. Tira o laço FOR e faça apenas o while usando o nome das colunas no própio código conforme abaixo:

```
//Montando o corpo da tabela
$table .= '<tbody >';
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
        $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
    }
}
```

Dentro do seu laço for aonde imprime a saída de cada cédula  você possuí a variável **$r**. Correto ?

portando para colorir a saída, digamos que o atributo de valor mensal pretendido seja uma coluna em sua tabela **qualite** que aqui chamaremos de **MensalPretendido** e o valor alcançado seja uma coluna aqui denominado **MensalAlcancado**.

você poderia alterar seu código e fazer isso:

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    if($r['MensalPretendido'] > $r['MensalAlcancado']){
      $table .= '<td style="background:red;">'.$r['MensalPretendido'].'</td>';
      $table .= '<td style="background:red;">'.$r['MensalAlcancado'].'</td>';
    }else{
      $table .= '<td style="background:green;">'.$r['MensagemPretendido'].'</td>';
      $table .= '<td style="background:green;">'.$r['MensalAlcancado'].'</td>';
    }
    //aqui concatena na variavel **$table** outras colunas da tabela se 
    //houver....
}
```

Ou seja; se o valor da coluna **MensalPretendido** for maior que o valor de **MensalAlcancado** imprime a cédula em vermelho caso contrário imprime em verde.

Mediante ao que passou tentei devolver a resposta de forma facíl de entendimento mas não tinha os nomes dos campos para reescrever o código então adapte ao seu projeto.

***Atualização***

Todas as respostas aqui fornecidas são baseadas em entendimento de lógica, tanto a minha resposta quanto a do magnifíco **Ricardo Pontual** foi fornecido a lógica completamente correta de se alcançar o resultado almejado! Agora se quer copiar e colar sem ter a preocupação de entender e depurar seu código vai precisar passar o acesso total a todo o seu ambiente para que tenhamos o mesmo entendimento da pessoa que modelou o código.

Primeiramente precisa configurar seu ambiente de programação para exibir erros e avisos, isso é feito alterando um diretiva dentro de seu php.ini chamada **display_erros** para **ON** ou então no topo de sua página php utilize

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

caso contrário fica difícil a compreensão do que está acontecendo. Gostaria muito que uma das duas respostas lhe ajude.

Comment: Primeiramente: Obrigada por responder! Em segundo lugar: Tentei usar seu código subistituindo por 'JAN_PREV' e 'JAN_REAL' que são as colunas de janeiro, por exemplo, mas a página parou de funcionar.

Comment: Atualiza sua pergunta e posta o código que colocou e o erro que deu por favor? aproveita e adiciona os sql os campos de sua tabela para entender o schema como ela foi montada!

Comment: Então, coloquei o banco na pergunta. Eu literalmente copiei o seu código e só troquei o nome das colunas, mas dá "Essa página não está funcionando".

Comment: @MarianaFerreira na lógica que o Rafael propos, você precisa usar o nome da coluna no lugar do índice. Ele colocou como exemplo "MensalPretendido" mas você precisa ver na tabela exata no banco. Você mencionou que é "JAN_PREV", e o exemplo é para o início da tabela, você precisa repetir o código e tratar as outras colunas, como imagino "FEV_PREV" e assim por diante, senão não irá funcionar, aproveite a ideia da lógica e tente adaptar, faça só com uma coluna inicialmente e depois adicione os outros mêses

Comment: Então, corrigi algumas coisas e adaptei pra o que eu precisava. Vou fazer um edit mostrando o resultado e o código. Obrigada aos dois.

Answer (score 1):

Seria simples comparar na linha que você gera a `td`, mas você está fazendo isso num `for` de maneira dinâmica, usando um índice e não nomes dos campos, o que dificulta.
Olhando o seu código, podemos perceber que a primeira coluna com o valor "previsto" é a quarta, se pensarmos no índice do array, índice 3 e a real índice 4.

Podemos então usar a seguinte lógica: *"Se a coluna de índice for ímpar, a partir da 3a será o valor previsto, e se par, o valor real"*
Então você pode criar duas variáveis, uma para o valor previsto e outra para o real, guardar seus respectivos valores de acordo com o índice (par ou ímpar), no seu caso a variável `$i`, e atribuir uma classe na `TD` de acordo com a cor de fundo que você quer.

Primeiro, adicione no seu `CSS` duas classes, por exemplo assim:

```
.fundoVerde {
   background-color: green;
   color: #fff
}
.fundoVermelho {
   background-color: red;
   color: #fff
}
```

Em seguida, no `for` que gera as colunas, implementar a lógica que propus acima:

```
$nomeClasse = 'class=""';
$prev = 0;
$real = 0;
for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
   if ($i >= 3) {
      // Se par
      if ($i % 2 == 0) {
         $real = $r[$fields[$i]];
         if ($real > $prev) {
            $nomeClasse = 'class="fundoVerde"'
         else
            $nomeClasse = 'class="fundoVermelho"';
         }
      } else {
         // se ímpar
         $nomeClasse = 'class=""';
         $prev = $r[$fields[$i]];
      }
   }
   // concatena a classe
   $table .= '<td '.$nomeClasse.'>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
}
```

A lógica é essa, pode ser que precise converter o valor para comparar ou algum pequeno ajuste.

Comment: Então, usei seu código e só mudei umas {} e ; mas o cabeçalho não apareceu, só um quadradinho vermelho apareceu no lugar. Vou editar mostrando o resultado.

Comment: Bom, esse código está baixo do cabeçalho, então é estranho não aparecer, precisa olhar o html que foi gerado pra entender. Veja também que, independente da lógia que propus, sempre será inserida a `td` normalmente, então não consigo visualizar onde pode não estar mostrando as colunas, sugiro da uma olhada no html e verificar o que ficou faltando