# Mudar a Cor da linha da tabela com base em um valor do Banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, css

Boa tarde

Estou construindo um sistema, que faço cadastro de pessoas no banco de dados e preciso que, quando eu selecionar um radio box na pagina `visita_registro.php` que faz eu incluir um registro no banco, grave na tabela **cor** o `id` da cor selecionada e os dados que aparecem na tabela da pagina `index.php` fiquem da cor que selecionei no radio box da página anterior.

As cores são verde, amarelo, vermelho e branco. Li um artigo que é parecido com o que quero fazer mas o *script* não deu certo no meu projeto.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, está meio complexa a explicação, mas espero que entendam.

Parte do arquivo visita_registro.php

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Registro de Visitas</p>
        </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form method="POST" action="visita_processa.php">
                    <!--Criando uma tag input com campo tipo hidden para enviar o id da linha que está em edição de forma oculta para o nosso arquivos de update -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                        <div class="form-group" class="styled-select">
                            <label for="pa">Situação:</label><br/>
                                <select name="situacao" class="form-control" >
                                    <option value="">Escolha o usuário</option>
                                    <?php
                                                $sql_at = "SELECT 
                                                            *
                                                             FROM 
                                                             rede_catarina.visitas_situacao
                                                            ORDER BY
                                                             id";

//Verifica se a consulta retornou mais de uma linha, se sim, mostra o conteúdo do banco,
                                                    $result_sql_at = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_at);
                                                        while($row_sql_at = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_sql_at) ) {
                                                        echo '<option value="'.$row_sql_at['id'].'">'.utf8_encode($row_sql_at['situacao'].'</option>');

                                                        }
                                            ?>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="mensagem">Obs. Visita:</label><br/>
                                <textarea name="mensagem" class="form-control" rows="5" ></textarea><br/><br/>
                            </div>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" id="cor" name="cor" value="verde"> Visita Realizada<br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" id="cor" name="cor" value="vermelho"> Visita com Alterações<br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" id="cor" name="cor" value="amarelo"> Apreciado pelo Ministerio Público<br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" id="cor" name="cor" value="branco"> Continuar Visitas<br><br><br> 
                                <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Você pode colocar no `value` do radio box o nome da cor de acordo com a opção escolhida, e dar um post nela ou usar Ajax para pegar esse valor..

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Alterar a cor de uma célula de acordo com o valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/312975/alterar-a-cor-de-uma-c%c3%a9lula-de-acordo-com-o-valor)

Comment: Leandro, pensei no seguinte, espero q tenha coerência meu pensamento: Preciso inserir o registro ali é que a linha da Index fique verde depois que selecionei o rádio box, ai o MP vai ver quando acessar que tá verde então eles lêem o registro e mudam para amarelo, ai eu quando acessar vou saber q eles visualizaram e deixaram um registro com o parecer, então vou lá e passo para branco depois de ler o parecer deles q o branco quer dizer continua a visita se for encerrar coloco inativo no cadastro

Comment: Na index.php tenho o echo que puxam os dados do BD,  coloquei o rádio box com o nome de cada cor que salvam na tabela cor e a id da cor fica na tabela cadastro, quero q quando puxar os dados da tabela cadastro para aparecer na tabela da página index.php faça a leitura da coluna cor e pinte a linha, porém não sei fazer não sei se tem como fazer isso em casa o javascript. Se alguém puder dar um apoio nessa situação. Fico muito agradecido

Comment: Se essa linha que você quer por a cor for uma Div, usando o Javascript você localiza a div `var div = document.getElementById('minha_div');` e coloca a cor nela usando o valor que veio da select do banco usando o **PHP** `div.style.background = <?PHP echo $cor; ?>;`. Recomendo por isso numa função `onLoad`.

Comment: Muito obrigado Leandro vou tentar essa alternativa. Parece bem simples espero que solucione meu problema.

Comment: Leandro, na minha pagina index.php não tem div vou postar parte do codigo: